# Is there a way to run a Busted test suite in parallel?

Tags: lua, lua-busted

The test suite for my Lua project is split up into multiple files inside the `spec/` directory.
Is there a way to ask busted to run those tests in parallel? If I call `busted` without any arguments it runs all the tests sequentially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing that seems to work is to use [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) to run multiple test scripts at once.

```sh
parallel busted -o utfTerminal ::: spec/*_spec.lua
```

The `-o utfTerminal` is to tell busted to use the familiar "green circles" output instead of the simplified text output it uses when its stdout is redirected.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand much about the Busted library, but apparently what you want is working with **multiple threads**

**Threads** are basically the process where the code executes line by line until the end. When we create more threads for a code, multiple loops, functions, etc ... within this new Thread, they executed simultaneously with the original code, without interfering in the process, that is, **more than one thing is executed in parallel.**

Unfortunately Lua does not contain a way to perform multiple threads, the most it has to work with threads is coroutines. However, there are libraries like [lua-llthreads](https://github.com/Neopallium/lua-llthreads) that perform this task, try it out and see what you think. By joining it with your code with Busted, you will be able to perform parallel tasks

Comment: I imagine it would be easier to run it as separate processes instead of threads. However, I don't know how to do that without messing up the stdout, with every process talking at the same time.

Comment: @hugomg 
you can try to create a new Lua script and run each one separately in different scripts with `os.execute()`

for example: you separate each of them into `script1.lua`, `script2.lua` and `script3.lua`, then you create a so-called `execute.lua` and do:


`os.execute("lua script1.lua")`
`os.execute("lua script2.lua")`
`os.execute("lua script3.lua")`

you can also use `io.popen()` but it usually serves to collect some return from cmd.

Comment: @hugomg I managed to solve your problem and/or clarify your question?